# Index merging in python

Tags: python, merge, indexing

I have a task of creating small indexes from a huge file using `spimi`.

I have been successful in splitting the index into small files.
Now I want to merge the indexes, such that the indexes values don't overwrite the keys.
Dictionary keys are terms and values are doc id. 
If I use the following method then it will overwrite for values with the same keys. 
I would really like that someone could suggest some good way to do this external merge sorting by opening multiple files at once.

```
example:
color[1:1,2,5]
color[1:,3,4,5]
after merging
color[1:1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here's my code:

```
def InvertedIndex():
  inputbuffer=dict()
  path="C:/Users/a_chav/Downloads/reuters21578.tar/reuters21578"
  count=0
  for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".p"):
      inputbuffer=pickle.load(open(filename,"rb"))
      keys=inputbuffer.keys()

      pickle.dump(outputbuffer,open("mainindex.p","a"))
      count=count+1
      print(count)
```

Comment: Please format the code and punctuate your text. This is just unreadable, and will be downvoted very quickly.

Comment: Example input is usually more useful than path to the file. Some people here will be familiar with Reuters collection but most of them probably not.

Comment: i know i can do the merging in memeory but task is to take the small indexes and merge them on the go  which is challenging and keeping track of the sorted order overwriting and adding new valus

Comment: what does `1:1` mean?  what about `1:`?  how are these represented in python?

Comment: well 1 is the dictionary  key and has value in list